# SSH From outside the local network

Tags: ssh

I opened port 22 on my modem and connected to my raspberry pi. Now when trying to login to pi from outside the local network using command: "ssh -P 22 WAN IP ADDRESS" it asks for a password which is not "raspberry". I was wondering if there is a default password for such connection or it's related to my modem (Mine is Actiontec C1000A).

Comment: @rob you've got it backwards, should be `pi@address`

Comment: What do you mean with "I opened port 22 on my modem"? There are mainly two things you can do to "open" the port 22: 1. Run some service on the modem (router) itself, listening on port 22 (most likely ssh). 2. Forward port 22 to your Raspberry Pi's local IP. Number two is the thing you want to do. And like the others say: do `ssh pi@WAN_IP_ADDRESS` to login to the user account `pi`. When omitting `pi@` you will login as the user with the name you have on the machine you are sitting at. And this user most likely does not exist on the RPi, so it will tell you always: your password is wrong.

Answer (score 2):

I actually just set this up on my raspberry pi/router earlier this morning.

If you're connecting via a linux machine, type this in the terminal:

```
ssh user@host
```

and replace user with the username and host with the WAN IP (i.e. pi@127.0.0.1 but with your public IP)

You will be prompted to type yes or no to continue connecting and it will ask for user@host's password.

Enter the password for that user and it should work fine.

I've just tested it myself.